# What does the "flip flop" hat mean? :-)

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

I got a secret hat! Is it magic? Am I being targeted by the NSA? Is the hat lined with tin foil? Does someone think I'm a flop, or does it just come with matching sandals? And if I'm a flip-flop - which kind is it, JK or D? (Ok that one was an EE joke).

Please enlighten me!

Comment: [Winter Bash 2015 Secret Hats](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/270789)

Comment: Voting up or down today (21/12/2015 UTC) seems to be the most likely culprit at this stage.

Comment: It means you're a political candidate.

Comment: @fixer1234: I would like to thank all of my supporter, and especially my wife Miche-, umm, I mean, Saran Netan-, uh, I mean, haven't actually met my wife yet. I wonder if Sanders is married.