# What is the purpose of these items

Tags: discussion

What do I do with these ridiculous hats. And my grammar may be wrong because I am a foreigner. Posting here is not easy - too many stupid rules.

[image]

Comment: These have to do with the [Winter Bash](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/)  You can turn them off from the snowflake menu in the top bar.

Comment: This cracked me up.  I voted to migrate this to the Meta site because it's about the functioning of the site.  It's annual holiday spirit.  See heavyd's comment.

Comment: OK, one more thing to waste my time.

Comment: Welcome, MVP Microsoft. There's lots of time to waste by asking silly questions about topics you don't seem to care about. It's up to you.

Comment: plus one cause you made me laugh (might be against rules... have to check meta)

Comment: " too many stupid rules." don't use this site then

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the "flip flop" hat mean? :-)](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/11049/what-does-the-flip-flop-hat-mean)

Answer (score 6):

It shows how awesome of a stackexchange user you are! Click the snowflake up top, and hit i hate hats

[image]

Comment: I am not awesome. I am 70% blind and I see no snowflakes. Maybe you can point them out to me.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer

Answer (score 5):

They are hats.

Officially?

> Stack Exchange invites you to celebrate the end of a great year …with
>   HATS! As you use your site, you'll discover hats and other items
>   hidden behind certain actions. Collect all of them, some of them, or
>   none of them, but be quick – the hats get put back in their boxes on
>   January 4th!

Unofficially? Well, they're fun cosmetic addons for your avatar that you get awarded for doing stuff around the sites.

If you don't want a hat, click on the snowflake and pick "I hate hats" and its gone.

Its a little like a festive, transient badge, and if it dosen't interest you you can just  ignore it

Comment: Hmm, the wife always says I am no fun because I do not go for stuff like that. But I guess for some people it is fun. So be it.